# Xcode 7 (iOS) - methods for working on alternative versions of the same project

Tags: ios, git, version-control, xcode7

I've been developing iOS apps in Xcode for a couple years and am still not clear on what is the best approach to creating alternative versions of the same project. Note that I am not talking about releasing different versions to the app store, but rather testing different versions during development. In the past, when I have tried the simple method of duplicating a folder in the Finder, Xcode seems to get confused, and in any case this implies renaming, with all its attendant problems. Snapshots have been phased out, but snapshots, like working with a single git fork, involves stepping backwards, when what I want is to work in parallel. Creating a new target, as far as I can see, requires copying over all the files and assets from the other target, though perhaps this is the safest and most efficient in the long run. Or is a git fork a better solution? But I don't see how to do this from within Xcode.

Comment: Creating a new target in an existing project doesn't require copying files.  In fact, you can pick and choose files to include in each target.

Comment: Owen, could you illustrate where you do that picking and choosing? When I use File>New>Target, I see no such options. Thanks

Comment: In Xcode, make sure the left and right panels are open.  In the left panel select a file, preferable a .m file.  In the right panel, scroll down to target membership.  That will let you check on or off membership in the target.

Comment: OK, thanks. Though with that method, altering a .m file will alter it for both targets, if I understand correctly. I will want some of these .m files to be different for different targets.

Comment: You'll have two files, add both of them to the project.  They can be in different subfolders.  It may be helpful to you if you make the names unique, so you'll know what you're editing - foobarTargetA.m, etc.  Click on each one for a different target.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with git but personally but this is what I personally do. I tag every release in my master branch in git. This way, if I want to work in parallel, I do the following steps :

> - create a new folder in Finder
> - git clone
> - git checkout <#tag or branch or #commit>
> - work on two projects without forking :)

I don't do this inside xcode but rather trough the terminal, since git options inside xcode only allow you to modify your current project.

Comment: Thanks, wheeliez. Could you give me a more concrete example, showing the correct git commands to use?

Answer (score 0):

I use git branches for this.  The current development version is always my master branch, and each time I release a new version I create a branch with the name of that version number.  Then I can easily switch between versions by, e.g.:

```
git checkout v2.4
```

That way if I do a bug fix in one of the older versions that needs to be brought forward into the current version, I can just commit the change to the old branch and then cherry-pick it into the master.

For development or testing of possible new features, I just create temporary branches off of master - then I can work on the new feature in the temporary branch, make whatever changes are necessary, and merge them back into the master branch when I'm done (or just scrap the temporary branch and be right back where I was, if the new feature turns out to be a bust).

How you set up your branches is up to you - the important thing is to be consistent with it - find a strategy that works for you, and use it consistently from one version to the next (especially if you have multiple developers).  That way you'll always be able to go back to any version of your application and be able to build and debug it.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. Does your method require the Terminal? Or could it be done via Xcode? And does it work for local git repositories?

Comment: Xcode is able to interface with git, but I've never used that capability so I don't know if it can handle basic branching or not.  I prefer to use the command line so I know exactly what's happening.

Comment: And yes, this will work with both local and remote git repositories.  I keep my temporary branches local, and just push the released version and master branches up to the remote repo.